# python count the distance to a number in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df where there is an integer column 'X'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})
```

I need to count the distance to the previous zero for each value in the df.

so the expected output will be

```
op = pd.DataFrame({'dist': [0 ,0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]})
```

I am able to do a for loop and implement the logic , but i guess there is a more pythonic way of doing it which i am missing.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
g = df['X'].eq(0).cumsum()
df['dist'] = np.where(g.eq(0), 0, df.groupby(g).cumcount())
print (df)
   X  dist
0  7     0
1  2     0
2  0     0
3  3     1
4  4     2
5  2     3
6  5     4
7  0     0
8  3     1
9  4     2
```

**Explanation**:

1. First compare by `0` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`)
2. Add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
3. Create counter per groups by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
4. Test first group of `g` before first `0`
5. Create new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
print (df.assign(mask = df['X'].eq(0),
                 g = df['X'].eq(0).cumsum(),
                 counter = df.groupby(g).cumcount(),
                 mask1 = g.eq(0),
                 dist = np.where(g.eq(0), 0, df.groupby(g).cumcount())))

   X   mask  g  counter  mask1  dist
0  7  False  0        0   True     0
1  2  False  0        1   True     0
2  0   True  1        0  False     0
3  3  False  1        1  False     1
4  4  False  1        2  False     2
5  2  False  1        3  False     3
6  5  False  1        4  False     4
7  0   True  2        0  False     0
8  3  False  2        1  False     1
9  4  False  2        2  False     2
```